# Binding TextBox WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, filter, textbox

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так:
В одном textBox все работает(который откреплён от DataGrid,
а в textBox который прикреплен к колонке DataGrid, почему-то не работает.
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="searchText" Margin="69,10,344,11"
                         Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        <DataGrid x:Name="DGR" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="239" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" ItemsSource="{Binding AllEmployee}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ID" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Number,Mode=TwoWay}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Content,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="TXTName" Width="100"  Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54"/>
    </Grid>


    public class Employee : ViewModelBase
    {
        public int Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set
            {
                number = value;
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
        private int number { get; set; }
        private string name { get; set; }
    }
}
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        string searchText = String.Empty;
       ICollectionView myDataView;
       public string SearchText
       {
           get { return searchText; }
           set
           {
               searchText = value;
               myDataView.Filter = FilterData;
           }
       }
       public bool FilterData(object item)
       {
           var value = (Employee)item;
           if (value == null || value.Name == null)
               return false;
           return value.Name.Contains(SearchText);
       }

        public ObservableCollection<Employee> myEmployee;
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> AllEmployee
        {
            get { return myEmployee; }
            set { myEmployee = value; }
        }
        public MainViewModel() 
        {
            AllEmployee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            this.Initialize();
        }
       private void Initialize()
        {
            myDataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myEmployee);
        }
    }
 }
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName] 
            String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataContext во втором случае берется за `ItemsSource="{Binding AllEmployee}"` DataGrid, поэтому привязка не проходит и соответственно не работает.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TXTName" Width="100" Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

заменить на:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TXTName" Width="100" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам Огромное.

Comment: @Евгений, рад помочь!

Comment: Может глупо мой вопрос будет написан, но я так понял, что вы это через отладку проверили, так вот у меня это: равносильно (как баран на новые ворота) единственное когда я проверял то обратил внимание на этот код, верно ли или нет вот проблема для меня которая настолько сложна.....

Comment: public bool FilterData(object item)
       {
           var value = (Employee)item;
           if (value == null || value.Name == null)
               return false;
           return value.Name.Contains(SearchText);
       }

Comment: Он или не он не пойму!!!

Comment: @Евгений, если честно, я ничего не понял

Comment: Вы через отладку ошибку мою выявили или же уже настолько рука набита, что сразу же было понятно, какую ошибку я допустил, просто у меня с отладкой трудности возникают пока.

Comment: Сразу увидел ошибку в привязке и написал, остальной код не проверял

Comment: Понятно, и ещё раз спасибо.